# How to insert into three tables at once in sql server 2012

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to do my final project for BSc, for that I am trying to make a Gym management system in C# and sql server2012. I have tables

```
(instructors,salary,members(students), fees, schedules)
```

While registration of new member i want to insert into 3 tables(members, fees, schedules) at once, but i have no idea how to do it, i really want help from you people to show a simple way out.
what query should i write to insert into all three tables at once.
this URL is the pic of my C# form, please check it.

http://s502.photobucket.com/user/ajmalajmal/media/membersdesign_zps83fd57c5.png.html?filters[user]=139364694&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=1

these are my tables in sql server

http://s502.photobucket.com/user/ajmalajmal/media/tablessssssssssssss_zps14a56a9d.png.html?filters[user]=139364694&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Comment: Please try to post these images in your post. This way it would be easier for the readers of your post to help you.

Comment: I don't think he has enough rep

Comment: You will need an insert query for each table.  My suggestion is to write a stored procedure with those queries and call it from your .net app.  By the way, adding tags for 3 different database engines when you are only using one makes your question ambiguous.  If you want to be a programmer you should realize how bad that is.

Comment: Yea, maybe you want to use a generated unique ID. You can make your database generate a new one everytime you insert a value. Also you don't want to make the user link the table, so the fee really shouldn't have a m_id input.

Comment: http://revanayya.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a transaction. It's not really the same as writing at once, but I think this is what you're looking for.

So in the SaveButton_Click event handler you do:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO members
(id, firstname, etc.)
VALUES (tbMemberID.text, tbFirstName.text, etc)

INSERT INTO fees
(id, amount, etc.)
VALUES (tbFeeID.text, tbAmount.text, etc)

INSERT INTO schedule
(id, session)
VALUES (tbScheduleID.text, tbSession.text)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
GO
```

Comment: thanks david for your answer, it works in sql server, but now i am trying to find out a way how to apply it in C#, in my C# form i have sqlconnection and insertcommand etc, but what is the syntax of transaction in there. if u can give a simple example for C# as well that would be great. tnx

Comment: in that case you can use SqlTransaction. transaction.BeginTransaction(); Then insert your things. Then transaction.Commit();

Comment: Short solution, generate an ID using Guid.NewGuid() then insert it in the sql using SqlCommand.Parameters.Add() See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: hi David this is what i made till now:</br> please check it</br>           http://pho.to/4rJck/mw       </br>
but i don't want to insert the m_id by myself, i want the form to automatically insert foreign key of FEES table as the current primary key of Members table which is being inserted. i made the m_id identity(1,1). other friends can also comment: @johnnyno

Comment: sorry i edited my comment, i want little more detail

Comment: Ok. First of all, don't ask a user to insert an ID as that is a system thing which the user has no business with. Remove those text fields and generate them by yourself.(see comment above). Just put the ID you generate for the member_id into a variable and use it for both queries.

Comment: i am stuck, couldn't understand how to use Guid.NewGuid() to get my ID. nd ya i removed the M_ID textboxes, only thing is to get the M_id primary key to insert into m_id foreign key.

Comment: Ah, I see your id field is an integer. Guid is a string. So either change it to string or use a sequence to generate your ID. See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: tnx, i did it this way:            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('members') ", con); con.Open(); int max = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); and then in insert into fees command in @m_id foreign key i put the max+1 value. anyway u were very helpful for me, after a long struggle i finally succeed to do it. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can create **view** merging data from those three tables
and then use **instead of trigger** to insert data into those tables with one **insert** statement.

**Create three tables**

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
[PrimaryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FieldA] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PrimaryKey] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE TableB(
[PrimaryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FieldB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PrimaryKey] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE TableC(
[PrimaryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FieldC] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TableC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PrimaryKey] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Create view**

```
CREATE VIEW ThreeTablesView 
AS SELECT dbo.TableA.FieldA, dbo.TableB.FieldB, dbo.TableC.FieldC
FROM dbo.TableA
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB ON dbo.TableA.PrimaryKey = dbo.TableB.PrimaryKey
INNER JOIN dbo.TableC ON dbo.TableA.PrimaryKey = dbo.TableC.PrimaryKey
```

**Create instead of trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER ThreeTablesView_InsertTrigger
ON [dbo].[ThreeTablesView]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TableA (FieldA) SELECT i.FieldA FROM INSERTED i;
INSERT INTO TableB (FieldB) SELECT i.FieldB FROM INSERTED i;
INSERT INTO TableC (FieldC) SELECT i.FieldC FROM INSERTED i;
END
```

**Insert data into three tables with single insert statement**

```
insert into ThreeTablesView (FieldA, FieldB, FieldC) values (N'aa', N'bb', N'cc');
```

Comment: thanks a lot dear johnnyno, and other people taking time to answer my question. this code looks great, but i it seems very difficult to apply it through c# on sql server, i will google it. any ways i got lots of idea from you people. thanks alot again

Comment: I looks difficult, but in general you just have to add view which acts as a virtual table. To support insert, update and delete operations on this view you need to use instead of triggers. Thats all.

Comment: Anyway if your solution not require **inserting to single table**. Depending on what you need like encapsulating insert logic or making 3 inserts atomic you can also use transaction or stored procedure (optionally with transaction).

Comment: You get a vote because this is actually a nice answer for the title question.

Comment: thanks dear, i wanted to vote for you and some other people, but since i am new, i don't have much reputation to vote.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only in Oracle you are able to insert into multiple tables in the same query. I don't think you can do this in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would not recommend but Triggers can be handy for situations like this.